# How to set float value 1.2 instead of 1.232223232 which comes from parser in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, string

I am calling web service in my application in which distance of Showroom Location from current location get parsed. eg 1.2322323, 12.2322322. This distance value I am showing in tableview.

By just giving `DistanceLabel1.text = aMarker.distance;` it prints the whole value. **So I need to just display the 1.2km, 12.23 km as label string in my tableview cell**.

I tried following way but giving me garbage:

```
DistanceLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.2f km ",aMarker.distance];
```

Here aMarker is parser attribute.

Comment: What is the type of `aMarker.distance` ?

Comment: float z = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f", value, nil] floatValue];

Comment: DistanceLabel1.text = [NSString stringwithformat:@"%f",z];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that `distance` is a string which is why you could assign it to the text. So:

```
CGFloat distance.   = [aMarker.distance floatValue];
DistanceLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.2f km", distance];
```

**NB**
In Objective-C you generally dont't start variable names with a capital letter. Names starting with capital letters are normally reserved for constants and symbols.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know NSString had a floatValue method, saves having to explicitly use a NSNumberFormatter!

Comment: using above giving me 12.53... with three dots not displaying "km"

Comment: It's overrunning the size of your label. Make your label wider.

Comment: Yups its working now. Is it necessary for me to make small later variable name for above??

Comment: It's not necessary but just be aware it's a common objC style and if it was my project I probably would change it.

Comment: Ok I will do the changes and  remember this one. Thanks for quick reply and tips:)